# C# many to one reflection from Datatable or DataRow

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, datarow, propertyinfo

I have a class

```
class Person {

 public string Name {get; set;}

 public int Age {get; set;}

 public string Phone {get; set;}

 // many other properties

}
```

Data for this person comes from a `DataRow`, the problem is that there isn't a one-to-one mapping, as illustrated below:-

```
 public DataRow doMapping()
{
 DataRow row = new DataRow();
 FillDataInto(row);
 Person p1 = new Person(); 

 p1.Name = row["FirstName"] + " " + row["LastName"];
 p1.Age = row["Age"];
 p1.Phone = row["Phone"] + " " + row["Extension"];
 p1.Prop1 = row["Prop1"];
 p1.PropXY = row["PropXY"];

 // many others ...
```

}

As illustrated some properties come from different columns of my database. I need some help in creating a reflection function to map row properties into `Person`

Currently i have the following, it will work for a one-to-one mapping,
(like the `Age` in the above example):-

```
public DataRow doMapping(){

 DataRow row = new DataRow();
 FillDataInto(row); 

 Person p1 = new Person();
 Type type = Person.GetType();
 PropertyInfo[] props = type.getProperties();

 foreach(PropertyInfo p in props)
 {
   string name = p.Name;
   p.SetValue(p1, row[name]);
 }
}
```

I just need to improve this to handle the previously mentioned situation.
(I can cleanup later, once i understand the core logic)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the columns required for Name and Phone in dataTable it self.

Add two new columns for Name and Phone and define it same as you the logic used for properties.
If you are loading this dataTable from database Select statement than add two new columns for Name and Phone in your SQL statement itself with the logic same as you used for properties.

Then your implementation for one to one property mapping may work.